# How to delete cloudinary image via PHP

Tags: php, delete-file, cloudinary, destroy

I have an cloudinary_id stored in DB and want to delete this image from Cloudinary.
According [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#destroy_method) I call desctroy method on uploadApi with id which returns result OK. But as I see the image is still available. Dont understand it.

Tis is the code:

```
$cloudinary = new Cloudinary($config);
return $cloudinary->uploadApi()->destroy($file_id);
```

This code returns **Cloudinary\Api\ApiResponse #d6b5 result => "ok"**

Can somebody tell me please what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Code looks fine, and if it returned you a valid result then your code isn't the problem. In the documentation they talk about CDN caching, have you tried to pass the **invalidate** parameter to bypass the CDN caching, as well as the **resource_type** parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudinary uses CDN to ensure fast delivery of the media resources. That being said, when deleting a media via API, you may need to pass the optional parameter "invalidation" set to true in order to invalidate that object in their CDN.
Here are their API documentation below:

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#destroy_method
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#delete_resources

You may use either upload API or admin API. Both achieve the same result.

Anthony

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for delay.